# Jasper-Struts2 plugin: compiled reports from external directory

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports, weblogic

I'm using Jasper with the Struts2 plugin to generate PDF reports for my web application, as described in [this tutorial](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.2/docs/jasperreports-tutorial.html).
The application uses Weblogic as app server and Apache as webserver in development environment, IIS in testing and production environments.
Locally I put the .jasper files under WEB-INF of the WAR section, which is then put in a EAR after compilation.

PDF generation works locally, passing a relative path (namely WEB-INF/jasper/template.jasper) to the result parameters of the "jasper" result in struts.xml . This does not work when the application is deployed as an EAR.

How can I get my application to find the .jasper template even when deployed as an EAR? I tried to pass in an absolute path pointing to a directory in the same server the EAR is in, but it doesn't work.

And by the way, is there a comprehensive guide to the Struts2 plugin for Jasper? I couldn't find anything except for that tutorial.

Comment: At present, no great way to do this. The `location` attribute is expected to be a physical file relative to the web app. The way the plugin is currently coded makes it a bit painful to work around that limitation, too, it's somewhat embedded in a too-large (~125 LOC) method. I'll put it on my pile of things to do.

Answer (score 0):

In weblogic domain home's `webapplications` tab; enable the option called `Archived Real Path Enabled`

works for me in weblogic 11g or later versions